# JDBC driver not found while debugging with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project that I can successfully compile and run through the command line. When I manually deploy a jar with dependencies in Tomee it works. However when I run the same project through IDEA I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

I think this is because my jar with dependencies has the jdbc driver included, but the IDEA run configuration deploys my classes and not the jar, so the driver is missing.

It seems to me that I need to somehow configure IDEA additionally even though I already have this in my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Am I indeed supposed to configure something else beside the pom?

I created the project without any IDE at first, because I was afraid it wouldn't work outside the IDE.

Comment: Make sure you load the class, `Class.forName("")`, the other check is to add the Jar as a dependency on your module

Comment: @Kennet Clark The line "Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");" throws this exception. I can add the jdbc jar manually to tomcat/lib and then it works with IDEA but I wanted to do this through Maven.

Comment: Did you import as a maven project?

Comment: @Steve C Yes, I think so. I opened the pom from IDEA and it recognized it. I have the full support for Maven in IDEA. I can run each phase from the Maven tool window. With every change to the pom IDEA auto-imports it.

Comment: Can you see the `jaybird-jdk18-3.0.0.jar` in the list of External Libraries in the "Project" panel on the left?

Comment: @Steve C Yes. Maven: org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18:3.0.0

Comment: Why are you building a "jar with dependencies"? JDBC drivers contain important information in their META-INF/services directory which can be lost when you do this. BTW, you have not needed to do `Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");` since Java 5 or so.

Comment: @Steve C Hmm, probably because I just don't know any better. I am new to Maven. Very well, I will rethink this and try another approach. Thank you.

Comment: @KennethClark The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been required in JDBC for ten years.